# ¿Como pasar lista de elementos a base de datos?

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Tengo en HTML  una etiqueta  y dentro de ella varias  utilizo estas etiquetas porque quiero simular una lista, donde pueda agregar elementos, seleccionarlos y poderlos modificas así como eliminar (todo esto ya lo hago por JavaScript). al momento de pasarlos a la base de datos por medio de PHP utilizo POST para enviar datos y estas etiquetas solamente envían los datos que se encuentran seleccionados (eso no lo sabía) entonces estoy buscando la manera de pasar todos los datos del  sin importar si están seleccionados o no, sin embargo no he podido pasar los datos a la base de datos, espero me puedan ayudar a solucionar esto, o bien otra manera de hacer esto aunque sean otras etiquetas.

Html

```
<form action="regSala.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="elementosHTML" name="elementos[]">
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
    </select>               
<input class="seleccion" type="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>
```

PHP

```
foreach ($_REQUEST["elementos"] as $option_value){
      echo $option_value;
 }
```

Comment: Sin los `[]`, algo así: `<select multiple class="form-control" id="elementosHTML" name="elementos">`.

Comment: No puede funcionar asi, si se quitan los corchetes no manda los datos ya sea seleccionados o no, con los corchetes envia los datos que están seleccionados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que la etiqueta `<option>` sea la indicada para hacer lo que dices. De cualquier forma aquí te dejo una forma de solucionarlo con javascript nativo y un input de tipo `hidden`:

```
<form onsubmit="return wtf_is(this);" action="regSala.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="elementosHTML" name="elementos[]">
        <option values="uno">Uno</option>
        <option values="dos">Dos</option>
        <option values="tres">Tres</option>
        <option values="cuatro">Cuatro</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="listValues">               
<input class="seleccion" type="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>


<script>
    var wtf_is = function(e){
        var values = [];
        for (var i = 0; i<e.elementosHTML.length; i++) {
            values[i] = e.elementosHTML[i].value;
        }
        e.listValues.value = values;
    };
</script>
```

Lo que hace es enviar 2 variables, una llamada "elementos" que contiene las opciones seleccionadas por si necesitas usarlas, y la otra se llama "listValues" que contiene todas las opciones seleccionadas y no seleccionadas.

Es muy importante que en PHP almacenes la variable listValues con un explode(). Ej:

```
$elementos = isset($_POST['elementos']) ? $_POST['elementos'] : null;
$listValues = isset($_POST['listValues']) ? explode(',', $_POST['listValues'][0]) : null;

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($elementos);
var_dump($listValues);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, tenia 3 dias batallando con lo mismo, me ayudaste bastante y despejaste otras dudas que tenia :D!

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren un par de cosas:

1. Asegúrate que las tags `<option>` tengan valores, si no como valor entonces como atributo (`value="algo"`).
2. Yo no había probado nunca el *select multiple*, pero bien podrías aventurarte y en su lugar usar `checkbox`. Si no te gustan las palomitas, puedes borrarlas luego con CSS, y/o asignar la etiqueta `label` para que al hacer clic en ella el `checkbox` también se active o desactive.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="elementos[a]" value="x" />
<label for="elementos[a]">Elemento A</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="elementos[b]" value="y" />
<label for="elementos[b]">Elemento B</label>
```

Eso ya debería arrojarte valores en el endpoint.

Por cierto, procura apegarte al método del query siempre. En el form estás usando **POST**, mientras que en tu **PHP** estás recogiendo ambas (GET y POST). Usar `$_REQUEST` puede ser peligroso en entornos de producción.

Comment: El `<label for="">` referencia a un atributo **id**.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, no sabia eso del $_REQUEST, me ayudo bastante :D!